# Phantom “new” e-mails

Tags: mail.app, email

Frequently when I launch Mail.app, it says "Connecting" for a while, then says “*X* new messages” when there are none.  The notification does not appear like it does when there are actually new messages.  Just the fine print in the lower left corner where on other occasions it says “no new messages.”  It did that again a few minutes ago.

Is there an explanation?

I thought maybe a message hit one of my rules, but all of my junk folders are empty, and the newest thing in the Trash is a message I put there myself some time ago.

First noticed many months ago and still happening on Ventura 13.0.1 (22A400)

Comment: Do you use POP or IMAP? I see that happen every so often on POP. I used to think it was the Exchange server I was using, but I've recently moved my entire domain, records & mail server to a completely different set of authorities & structures… & it still occasionally does it, though less frequently. Still on Mojave.

Comment: One account is Exchange and three are IMAP.  Which one, if any, the message points to is unknown.

Comment: @WGroleau First is to try the accounts one by one - disable them all and try one by one. As IMAP or exchnage the emails are all on the servers so you will not lose mail

Comment: It's merely a curiosity.  I might do that.  But since it is intermittent, it might not be worth the effort.